# HOw to resolve this error after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Please guide how to resolve this issue

**ERROR MESSAGE-**

..\src\fibers.cc(70): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Handle' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automa
tion\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(83): error C2065: 'Handle': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automati
on\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

```
..\src\fibers.cc(83): error C2065: 'handle': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automati
on\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(83): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_mo
dules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-aut
omation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(87): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC
-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-we
b-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-aut
omation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C2059: syntax error: '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_module
s\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C2065: 'T': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\no
de_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C2923: 'v8::Persistent': 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [C:\Us
ers\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(92): error C3203: 'NonCopyablePersistentTraits': unspecialized class template can't be used as a templ
ate argument for template parameter 'M', expected a real type [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\no
de_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(97): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-aut
omation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(97): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC
-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(101): error C2065: 'Handle': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automat
ion\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(101): error C2065: 'handle': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automat
ion\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(101): error C2275: 'uni::GetterCallbackInfo': illegal use of this type as an expression [C:\Users\MOHA
S076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  ..\src\fibers.cc(59): note: see declaration of 'uni::GetterCallbackInfo'
..\src\fibers.cc(101): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'info' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-t
rp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(105): error C2065: 'T': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\n
ode_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(105): error C2923: 'v8::Persistent': 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [C:\U
sers\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(105): error C3203: 'NonCopyablePersistentTraits': unspecialized class template can't be used as a temp
late argument for template parameter 'M', expected a real type [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\n
ode_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(105): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(105): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(109): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(109): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(109): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(109): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(113): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

..\src\fibers.cc(113): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(113): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(113): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(117): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(117): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(117): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(117): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(121): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(121): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(121): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(121): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(125): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(125): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(125): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(125): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(129): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(129): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(129): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(129): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(133): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(133): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(133): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(133): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(137): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(137): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(143): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(143): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(147): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-w
eb-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(147): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(150): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-au
tomation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(150): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SB
C-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(807): error C2955: 'Fiber': use of class template requires template argument list [C:\Users\MOHAS076\D
esktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  ..\src\fibers.cc(295): note: see declaration of 'Fiber'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2015\BuildTools\VC\include\vector(677): error C2955: 'Fiber': use of cla
ss template requires template argument list (compiling source file ..\src\fibers.cc) [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp
-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  ..\src\fibers.cc(295): note: see declaration of 'Fiber' (compiling source file ..\src\fibers.cc)
..\src\fibers.cc(814): error C2182: 'init': illegal use of type 'void' [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-auto
mation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(814): error C2448: 'init': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition [C:\Users\MO
HAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(829): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'node::addon_register_func' of greater size
 [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(829): error C2065: '_register_fibers': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\MOHAS076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-te
st-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\coroutine.cc(138): warning C4552: '!': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect [C:\Users\MOHA
S076\Desktop\SBC-trp-web-test-automation\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
```